# How to play .ts files using AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, avplayer, avkit

I'm working on a streaming project and i have to create player abstraction to play .ts files. sadly i didnt find any info(excluding 10 year old thread) how to make avplayer play .ts extensions. can anyone help me out? what's the best practice to do it correctly?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237312/avplayer-play-ts-file may be helpful

Comment: yeah, thats what I was reffering. I really hoped something changed since that thread.

Comment: Years ago I played such files with software video players. There was a trick to rename the ending to mpeg or mp3, because ts ist mpeg coded... So if you rename the file from .ts to .mpeg or mp3 can be a try

Comment: sadly mpeg format doesn't work too

Comment: ok sorry have luck

Comment: @Sevenfortyseven You need to check how to play (H.264) bytes in AVPlayer, then extract them (H.264 frame bytes) from the TS file. Also check if there is a Swift-based TS file remuxer that can maybe extract the data from TS.